# Datastore Remote API Through Local Application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm basically just trying to access the Remote API of an app I threw up onto the datastore. I can access it just fine through the shell but can't within a local application script.

I've tried this:

```
from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
import getpass

def auth_func():
  return (raw_input('Username:'), getpass.getpass('Password:'))

remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(None, '/remote_api', auth_func,
                               'your_app_id.appspot.com')
```

But keep getting a `HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found` even though everything seems right (path and application name). Did something change recently on app engine?

Comment: is remote api on in your application's yaml?

Comment: yes. It works just fine in the shell, but it keeps failing in the script.

Comment: hmmm then could you check the exact call that gets sent out from the shell, and use logging to check what you send from the script? There might be some slight difference there

Comment: You could do that? how?!

Comment: To double check, is your path setting right? The default used by the shell is `'/_ah/remote_api'`. Or do you also override it when you use the shell.

Comment: I thought the default was `/remote_api` https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi If i try /_ah/remote_api , I get an EOF error.